# lattice graphics in a R widget

Tags: r, lattice, gwidgets

Using the gWidgets package I have made a R widget that shows a lattice graphic when the user click on a button. 
The function producing the graphic (`fgraph()` below) runs well outside the widget. However the graphic at the topleft corner does not appear in the widget.
Here is a reproducible code:

```
library(lattice)

sims <- data.frame(
    y=rnorm(8), 
    A=factor(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)), 
    B=factor(c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)),
    C=factor(c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))
)

fgraph <- function(sims){
    plot(
    dotplot(y ~ A | B+C , data = sims, 
             ylab="Zeta (mV)",  
            panel = function(...){
                panel.abline(v=c(1,2), col = "grey", lty = 2)
                panel.grid(col = "grey", lty = 2, v=0)
                panel.xyplot(..., pch = 16, col="black")
            }
        )
    )
}

library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")

win <- gwindow("Simulation")
GROUP <- ggroup(cont=win)

graphwindow <- ggraphics(container = GROUP,
    expand = TRUE, ps = 11)

GoGroup <- ggroup(horizontal=FALSE, container = GROUP)
addSpring(GoGroup)
Simulates <- gbutton(text="Simulates", container = GoGroup, 
    handler = function(h, ...) {
        fgraph(sims)
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this without the `fitAV3` object. It may be an issue with `cairoDevice`, as `ggraphics` doesn't really do much in addition.

Comment: @jverzani Thanks for your attention. I have edited my post to replace the code with a reproducible one.

Comment: As I thought, this is reproducible with just cairoDevice, but only under Windows. It worked fine as is with my Mac under X11. Not sure what to suggest, as this is well beyond my abilities. Likely it goes back to the gtk build for windows.

Comment: @jverzani Maybe you know a good place where I could point this bug out ? Should I write to the maintainer of cairoDevice ?

Comment: He might now. That's where I would start.